# It is possible to give access to VM in hyper-v windows server 2012 outside the server?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, virtual-machines, hyper-v-server-2012

I have server with **windows server 2012** and **hyper-v**.

I have created **VM** on it, can i access this **VM** *console* from any browser?

*java access* or something like **proxmox** in `Linux`.

I just want my client to take care of his **VM** from restart and install OS without making contact with me.

Comment: Clarify what you mean by accessing the VM. Do you wish to expose the network interface of the VM so services it hosts are available externally, or do you wish to expose management control of the VM itself (i.e. console-level access) so other administrators can manage its software and virtualized hardware configuration?

Comment: I mean outside access of the VM management, i control the whole hyper-v from the main server with remote desktop that's is fine, what i asking about that if customer take VM from me Linux or windows i will give him root or administrator but if the vm is frozen or need a rescue or restart is there any outside access to console for him to do that without making contact with me?? just for single VM not for all VMs every client with his VM..

Answer (score 0):

Granting [remote access to Hyper-V Manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/manage/remotely-manage-hyper-v-hosts) could do this. This user would need to be a domain user and if the host is on the same domain.  Further, they would gain complete control of that host.

[SCVMM can do full role based access control of VMs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/system-center/system-center-2012-R2/gg696971(v=sc.12)). And you can grant self service based on tools like App Controller. But you may not have SCVMM, and it is more to set up.

You could write a script to reboot their VM for them, such as with PowerShell. And give them access to run it from some management host.  However, you expressed desire for them to see a console, which is not going to be easy without those management tools.